# What’s the docker compose equivalent of my docker command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu

I’ve been using the command line for docker for 2 weeks and just learned how to use `docker compose` yesterday using the excellent [documentation I found at Jellyfin](https://jellyfin.org/docs/general/installation/container/). I got a Jellyfin container up and running in a jiffy on my new Ubuntu Server (22.04.4 LTS) and couldn’t be happier.

I thought I’d go back to Emby and learn how to create a compose file as an exercise.

I currently use the following command line to successfully bring up Emby:

```
docker run -d \
        --name embyserver \
        --volume /home/udance4ever/emby:/config \
        --volume emby-cache:/cache \
        --volume /home/udance4ever/mnt/userdata/kodi:/userdata/kodi \
        --device /dev/dri:/dev/dri \
        --publish 8096:8096 \
        --publish 8920:8920 \
        --env UID=1001 \
        --env GID=1001 \
        --restart unless-stopped \
                emby/embyserver:latest
```

I can’t figure out the difference between the above command line and the following compose file I “translated”:

```
version: '3.5'

volumes:
  emby-cache:

services:
  embyserver:
    image: emby/embyserver:latest
    container_name: embyserver
    user: 1001:1001

    ports:
      - "8096:8096"
      - "8920:8920"

    volumes:
      - /home/udance4ever/emby:/config
      - emby-cache:/cache
      - /home/udance4ever/mnt/userdata/kodi:/userdata/kodi

    devices:
      - /dev/dri:/dev/dri

    restart: 'unless-stopped'
```

I use `docker compose up -d` to bring up the server and it just keeps restarting:

```
a0b30f16f381   emby/embyserver:latest   "/init"                About a minute ago   Restarting (1) 3 seconds ago
```

I’m real new to docker so I don’t know where to begin to debug this compose file (and reverted to recreating the container using the command line which, again, works without error)

I’m posting here because I think it’s less about Emby and more about my understanding of how Docker compose works and its grammar.

Why does my compose file produce different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compose file looks mostly correct, but there's a small difference between the `user` specification. In your original `docker run` command, you're using environment variables (--env UID=1001 and --env GID=1001) to set the `user`, while in the docker compose file, you are using the `user` directive directly.

To make your Docker Compose file equivalent to the original `docker run` command, you can add the environment section for setting the **UID** and **GID**. You can try out the below compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

volumes:
  emby-cache:

services:
  embyserver:
    image: emby/embyserver:latest
    container_name: embyserver
    
    ports:
      - "8096:8096"
      - "8920:8920"

    volumes:
      - /home/udance4ever/emby:/config
      - emby-cache:/cache
      - /home/udance4ever/mnt/userdata/kodi:/userdata/kodi

    devices:
      - /dev/dri:/dev/dri

    environment:
      - UID=1001
      - GID=1001

    restart: 'unless-stopped'
```

After making these changes, try running `docker-compose up -d` again, and it should bring up the Emby server without continuously restarting.

Comment: wow! that is such a subtle difference and sure enough, it worked - thank you :)  what documentation may I read to better understand when the user directive is relevant vs user environment variables?  I poked around a little bit and only see articles on one or the other.